# Traefik HTTPS entry points configurations not working via lets encrypt

Tags: docker, docker-compose, lets-encrypt, traefik

Having some real issues getting HTTPS entrypoints working from my Traefik docker container.

I was trying to follow the guidelines over at https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/docker-and-lets-encrypt/

Also have tried various bits from https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/examples/ and https://ian-says.com/articles/traefik-proxy-docker-lets-encrypt/ and various other places

It all works fine in http, but https gives me a connection refused, and no https entrypoint is active in the traefik web portal.

When I check port 443 externally it says its closed, however there is no firewall, and its not already in use (see `docker ps` below), so all I can think is that the traefik container itself isn't setup correctly for https?

**My question:** How do I get HTTPS working on traefik? Also how do I see the traefik logs to get more info? `docker-compose logs -f reverse-proxy` is empty

**traefik.toml**

```
defaultEntryPoints = ["https","http"]
debug = true

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]

[acme]
email = "email@domain.com"
storage = "/home/project/acme.json"
caServer = "https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
entryPoint = "https"
  [acme.httpChallenge]
  entryPoint = "http"

[[acme.domains]]
  main = "domain.com"
  sans = ["app.domain.com", "api.domain.com"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik
    command: --api --docker
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080" # The Web UI (enabled by --api)
    networks:
      - web
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /opt/traefik/traefik.toml:/home/project/traefik.toml
      - /opt/traefik/acme.json:/home/project/acme.json
  api:
    build:
      context: ./api/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
    - ~/api:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - web
    restart: always
    labels:
    - "traefik.enable=true"
    - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:api.domain.com"
    - "traefik.docker.network=web"
  webapp:
    build:
      context: ./webapp/
      dockerfile: DockerfileNode
    volumes:
      - ~/webapp:/app
    networks:
      - web
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:app.domain.com"
      - "traefik.docker.network=web"
      - "traefik.enable=true"
    expose:
      - 8188
networks:
  web:
    external: true
```

**screengrab of my traefik portal**
(note: only http entry points, no https)

[image: traefik portal showing no https entry points]

**docker ps**

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                              NAMES
d956a9d25ace        webapp       "/usr/bin/kafka-sock…"   18 minutes ago      Up 16 minutes       8188/tcp                                                           webapp_1
e46693c8ca3e        api          "docker-php-entrypoi…"   21 minutes ago      Up 16 minutes       80/tcp                                                             api_1
321c5efc720b        traefik      "/traefik --api --do…"   2 hours ago         Up 16 minutes       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   reverse-proxy_1
```